# how can I pass a variable to a SoQL query using Bash

Tags: bash, curl, quotes, soql

I need to pass a variable to a SoQL query to then make a Curl request. This is an example of code.

```
day=$(date -d "yesterday" +'%d/%m/%Y')
query1="SELECT name WHERE data=${day}"
query1=${query_1/ / /%20}

curl "https://url/file.json?\$query=${query1}"
```

I receive the following error:

```
{"message":Invalid SoQL query","error code":"query.soql.invalid","data":{}}
```

In the 'Where' I have tried with $day, "$day","${day}".

But if I introduce for example query1='SELECT name WHERE data=24/05/2020' works correctly.

I need help because I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: `query1="SELECT name WHERE data=${day}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query1="SELECT name WHERE data=${day}"
```

or

```
query1="SELECT name WHERE data=`day`"
```